# Unable to import the excel data for only 'User' table creation in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, import

During `import` of `excel` data into SQL Server 2012 Express for `User` only i am getting the error. The Error is as mention below

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.
```

And the my import statement TSQL code is as follows:

```
Use DB1;
    Go
    select * INTO User
    from openrowset('MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\DBTableDataRecords\User.xlsx; HDR=yes; IMEX=1',
    'select * from [User$]');
    Go
```

**NB:** From the above TSQL code i am able to import excel data for creation of other tablename (Except User table name). Even I have check the `MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider link server object. Where provider option of `'Allow inprocess'` is enable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting brackets around the user table like this

```
select * INTO [User]
```

"User" is a reserved word. By putting brackets around it you are basically telling SQL Server to look at this as an object and not a reserved word.

Even though SQL Server allows you to get around issues like this by using brackets, it's generally advisable to avoid naming objects with reserved words